# Axes.boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'

Tags: python, seaborn

[image]

When I created the code with the same structure as Google Colab's documentation, it returns an error:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_clean, x="funnel", y="ctr", hue="funnel", fill=False, gap=.1)


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-2814d552d352> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sns.boxplot(data=df_clean, x="funnel", y="ctr", hue="funnel", fill=False,  gap=.1)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1440     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441         if data is None:
-> 1442             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1443 
   1444         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: Axes.boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'
```

Answer (score 0):

This argument was added in version v0.13.0: https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.13.0.html#other-features-enhancements-and-changes

You need to update your seaborn to use it.